# How to display SVN revision on front page of multi-file LaTeX document?

Tags: svn, latex, version-control

I am writing a large LaTeX document, and I would like to display
the current SVN revision number on the title page. The problem is
that the LaTeX document is split into several files `root.tex`,
`ch1.tex`, `ch2.tex`, ...

I inserted $Revision$ in the `root.tex` file, so that it is
displayed on the front page.

Of course, I also ran

```
svn propset svn:keywords 'Revision' root.tex
```

But the problem is that this $Revision$ variable in `root.tex`,
naturally, is not updated if I only modify the `ch2.tex` file,
for example, and commit to SVN. So the PDF will still display the old revision number.

I artificially have to modify
`root.tex` as well, if I want the new SVN revision number to be
displayed. And just `touch root.tex` won't do it because SVN is
smart. I actually have to change some text, at least add some space or so
in `root.tex`.

What's the best way to solve this properly?

Answer (score 3):

A quick perusal of CTAN, turned up the [svn-multi](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/svn-multi/) package.  From the README

> This package lets you typeset keywords of the version
>   control system Subversion inside your LaTeX files anywhere
>   you like. Unlike the very similar package 'svn' the usage of
>   multiple files for one LaTeX document is well supported.